# Swipe card does not work on iOS but perfectly on Android - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel, swipe, card

I have an app like tinder where user can swipe card to like or dislike.
I use flutter_card_swiper (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_card_swiper) package to swipe cards, and carousel_slider (https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) to see user's pics into the card.

On Android, all is good and I can swipe normally, but when I test on iOS I can't swipe when my finger start from the card itself. I need to start from outer sides to swipe.

Here my code :

```
Expanded(
                            child: CardSwiper(
                                cardsCount: userListData.length,
                                cardBuilder: (context, swipeIndex) {
                                  return Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      child: SwipeCardWidget(
                                          currentSwipeIndex: swipeIndex));
                                }),)
```

Basically, I need to start the swipe in the container's padding zone.

Here my `SwipeCardWidget` :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
    future: _data,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else {
        List<UsersModel> usersListData = snapshot.data as List<UsersModel>;
        List imagePathList = [];

        imagePathList.clear();
        for (var i in usersListData[widget.currentSwipeIndex].sports) {
          var imagePath = Utils.getImagePath(i);
          imagePathList.add(imagePath);
        }
        return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                height: 700,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                // border:
                // Border.all(width: 0, color: googleColor)),
                child: CarouselSlider(
                    items: usersListData[widget.currentSwipeIndex]
                        .pics
                        .map(
                          (item) => ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              child: Image.network(
                                item,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                    carouselController: _controller,
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        scrollPhysics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        initialPage: 0,
                        height: 700,
                        viewportFraction: 1.0,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        onPageChanged: (indexCarousel, reason) {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentIndexCarousel = indexCarousel;
                          });
                        }))),
            Positioned(
              top: 10,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: usersListData[widget.currentSwipeIndex]
                    .pics
                    .asMap()
                    .entries
                    .map((entry) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 80.0,
                    height: 8.0,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(
                            _currentIndexCarousel == entry.key
                                ? 0.9
                                : 0.4)),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _controller.previousPage();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _controller.nextPage();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios))
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 20.0,
              left: 20.0,
              child: BlurryContainer(
                blur: 20,
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '${usersListData[widget.currentSwipeIndex].name} - ',
                            style: stylePreviewTitle,
                          ),
                          ...List.generate(
                            imagePathList.length,
                            (index) => Row(
                              children: [
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: 30,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    imagePathList[index] ?? '',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        usersListData[widget.currentSwipeIndex]
                            .age
                            .toString(),
                        style: stylePreviewContent,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        usersListData[widget.currentSwipeIndex].city,
                        style: stylePreviewContent,
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
                bottom: 15,
                right: 15,
                child: IconButton(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.25),
                  iconSize: 30,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const HelpPage()),
                    );
                  },
                ))
          ],
        );
      }
    });
```

}

On Android, it works perfectly but not on iOS. I also tried with swipe_cards (https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_cards) package

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after hours... The problem came from the stack. On Android, no problem, but on iOS the swipe only applied on the top stack's element. So Swipe was working but only on my IconButton.

The solution was to add a container at the end of the stack with `Colors.transparent`, so all the card is swipable.